# Syntax Error In Query with selectRaw and time diff

Tags: sql, laravel

please advice how to correct this query

```
        $no_of_hours = DB::Table('shifts')
            ->where('time_sheet_id','=', $timesheet_id->id)
            ->selectRaw("SELECT time(sum(TIMEDIFF( 'shift_end_time', 'shift_start_time' )))")
            ->get();

               return $no_of_hours;
```

im getting following error

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT time(sum(TIMEDIFF( 'shift_end_time', 'shift_start_time' ))) from `shifts`' at line 1 (SQL: select SELECT time(sum(TIMEDIFF( 'shift_end_time', 'shift_start_time' ))) from `shifts` where `time_sheet_id` = 35)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a sintax error probably because you don't have to write the `SELECT` keyword in the `selectRaw` function ( the keyword is added implicity by the query builder in this case ):

```
->selectRaw("time(sum(TIMEDIFF( 'shift_end_time', 'shift_start_time' )))")
```